# Macro Excel - Salvar imagem em gráfico exportar para diretório e importar para formulario

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Atualizei minha versão do Office para a 2016 e algumas macros deixaram de funcionar adequadamente. A rotina quando executada de forma isola funciona adequadamente, mas, quando entra em um processo deixa de funcionar. A macro em questão faz os seguintes precedimentos. Copia um Range:

```
Set rng = .Range("S1:W4")
rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
```

Cria um gráfico:

```
Set cht = .ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, rng.Width, rng.Height)
```

Cola a imagem no gráfico
Exporta a imagem no formato JPGEG para uma pasta.

Como informado, a rotina funciona se utilizada separadamente. Mas quando executo o formulário, a rotina deixa de funcionar. O gráfico é exportado, mas, sem imagem. O tamanho do arquivo também fica reduzido.

Comment: Tudo indica que o problema não é uma atualização de versão necessariamente, mas condições adversas *de execução*. A sua chamada `.Range("S1:W4")`, por exemplo, implicitamente executa a função `Range` para a aba ativa da planilha ([`ActiveWorksheet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff822753.aspx)). Talvez no momento em que você executa essa chamada "dentro do formulário" ou "dentro de um processo" (seja lá o que isso quer dizer, já que você não contextualizou adequadamente), não há aba ativa ou não é a esperada. Sugiro alterar o código para invocar a função na aba correta.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui identificar o problema: Na versão anterior eu copiava a imagem do intervalo, criava um gráfico com as dimensões do intervalo e colava diretamente a imagem copiada no gráfico.

o problema resolveu ao incluir o comando `cht.Activate` antes de do procedimento `cht.Chart.Paste`.

Comment: Por nada. Fico feliz que conseguiu resolver. Mas eu editei a sua resposta para tirar os "obrigado" e "cordialmente". É que este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour], ok? E, seja bem vindo ao SOPT! :)

Comment: P.S.: Como foi você mesmo que respondeu, você ainda não pode aceitar a resposta (o sistema impede isso por uns 2 dias, eu acho, pra motivar outras pessoas a responderem também). Mas, não deixe de voltar aqui e [aceitar a resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) depois desse período, ok? Isso é importante para de fato marcar a sua pergunta como concluída e ajudar outras pessoas com problemas similares.